# What is the equivalent of Autofac's aggregate services in Microsoft's dependency injection framework

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

There is a C# asp.net core project that I'm seeing the number of injected interfaces in some constructors keeps growing. It's expected it may exceed 30 or 40 interfaces in some cases.

A bit of googling got me to [Autofac's Aggregate Services](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/aggregate-services.html). My question is that whether there's an equivalent in asp.net core's DI framework to avoid passing many interfaces to constructors?

Comment: I doubt there is an equivalent, asp.net core DI is much less sophisticated than autofac. But you can use autofac itself instead of default DI container.

Comment: `may exceed 30 or 40 interfaces` - Sounds like you need to [refactor to aggregate services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). If you have more than 4 or 5 constructor parameters, it is a code smell that you probably have a service that is violating the SRP. I wouldn't suggest relying on a DI container feature to address what is so clearly an application design issue.

Comment: 100+ for @NightOwl888. 30 to 40 dependencies is a really bad thing. Autofac's Aggregate Services by itself are a bad idea, because it promotes grouping dependencies instead of hiding their complexity behind a facade. The main example in Autofac's documentation is the use of base classes, but that by itself is a bad idea, because base classes typically lead to SRP violations.

Answer (score 6):

As Evk mentioned in the comments, the dependency injection container at `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` is deliberately a very simple one. If you are in need of more powerful features, you should consider switching to a full fletched DI container instead. ASP.NET Core is built to allow swapping out the DI container, and it’s actually not too difficult to do so. [Autofac has a guide](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html) on how to do it.

That being said, Autofac’s aggregate services are not that much magic. Sure, you could build something like Autofac did and use Castle DynamicProxy to automatically implement the aggregate service. But you could also simply create such an aggregate service by hand:

```
public class MyAggregateService
{
    public IFirstService FirstService { get; }
    public ISecondService SecondService { get; }
    public IThirdService ThirdService { get; }
    public IFourthService FourthService { get; }

    public MyAggregateService (IFirstService first, ISecondService second, IThirdService third, IFourthService fourth)
    {
        FirstService = first;
        SecondService = second;
        ThirdService = third;
        FourthService = fourth;
    }
}

// then register that in the container
services.AddTransient<MyAggregateService>();

// and depend on it in the controller
public MyController (MyAggregateService aggregateService)
{ … }
```

Sure, you have to write a bit more, but it’s actually not that much more. And if you can do without those advanced features that Autofac offers, this is actually pretty simple and quickly done.

Answer (score 2):

You have two alternatives here because there is no equivalent to **Autofac Agregate Services** in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

### 1. Create a basic AggregateServices Implementation for your interfaces.

As you can imagine, you just need to create a class that implements the interface and encapsulate the constructor injection.

```
 public class SomeAggregateService
 {
   public IFirstService FirstService{get;private set;}
   public ISecondService SecondService{get;private set;}
   public IThirdService ThirdService{get;private set;}
   public IFourthService FourthService{get;private set;}

   public SomeController(
     IFirstService firstService,
     ISecondService secondService,
     IThirdService thirdService,
     IFourthService fourthService)
   {
     FirstService = firstService;
     SecondService = secondService;
     ThirdService = thirdService;
     FourthService = fourthService;
   }
 }
```

#### Pros

- Simple
- Quick to implement

#### Cons

- It still represents some kind of cluttering.
- It has a maintenance cost (low).

### 2. Implement Autofac with Microsoft.Extensions

As mentioned before, you can still replace the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection implementation with yours favorite container.

In case of Autofac, you should follow the next steps:

1. Install the integration package `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.
2. You need to modify your Program class and add Autofac services.

   ```
   public class Program
   {
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
   // The ConfigureServices call here allows for
   // ConfigureContainer to be supported in Startup with
   // a strongly-typed ContainerBuilder.
   var host = new WebHostBuilder()
       .UseKestrel()
       .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
       .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
       .UseIISIntegration()
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .Build();

   host.Run();
   }
   }
   ```
3. In the ConfigureServices method of your Startup class
   3.1. Register services from the IServiceCollection into the ContainerBuilder via Populate.
   3.2. Register services into the ContainerBuilder directly.
   3.3. Build your container.
   3.4. Create an AutofacServiceProvider using the container and return it.
   3.5. In the Configure method of your Startup class, you can optionally register with the `IApplicationLifetime`.ApplicationStopped event to dispose of the container at app shutdown.

   ```
    public class Startup
    {
      public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
      {
     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
       .AddEnvironmentVariables();
       this.Configuration = builder.Build();
   }

   public IContainer ApplicationContainer { get; private set; }

   public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

   // ConfigureServices is where you register dependencies. This gets
   // called by the runtime before the Configure method, below.
   public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
   // Add services to the collection.
   services.AddMvc();

   // Create the container builder.
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

   // Register dependencies, populate the services from
   // the collection, and build the container. If you want
   // to dispose of the container at the end of the app,
   // be sure to keep a reference to it as a property or field.
   //
   // Note that Populate is basically a foreach to add things
   // into Autofac that are in the collection. If you register
   // things in Autofac BEFORE Populate then the stuff in the
   // ServiceCollection can override those things; if you register
   // AFTER Populate those registrations can override things
   // in the ServiceCollection. Mix and match as needed.
   builder.Populate(services);
   builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IMyType>();
   this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

   // Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
   return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
   }

   // Configure is where you add middleware. This is called after
   // ConfigureServices. You can use IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices
   // here if you need to resolve things from the container.
   public void Configure(
   IApplicationBuilder app,
   ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
   IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
   {
     loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
     loggerFactory.AddDebug();

     app.UseMvc();

     // If you want to dispose of resources that have been resolved in the
     // application container, register for the "ApplicationStopped" event.
     // You can only do this if you have a direct reference to the container,
     // so it won't work with the above ConfigureContainer mechanism.
     appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
   }
   }
   ```

#### Pros

- It offers complete support.

#### Cons

- It means a setup effort.
- It is tight to Autofac.

Answer (score 1):

A facade pattern is universally used for this in big software projects. The facade pattern is not worked out in DI so lots of problems can exist because of this. A facade pattern is at the logic level, most of DI examples you see are physical and then its sometimes to late! With a facade pattern you reduce complexity of the controller by grouping logic dependencies in a facade service at a higher level and inject that facade service in a constructor. With that facade service you delegate to the underlying related dependencies. The wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) gives a very good explanation how to and what is.

There is also a big warning here! If you develop your project you should already make a good composition of your system. Divide your system in subsystems. Those subsystems can be good candidates for facade services. If you don't do this your software can be a mess.

At physical level you create a Aggregate service but at logical level its a facade you need to define. If you find those facade services at the start of your project it will make your life much easier then when you will have to do it at the end because then it might be much harder.

nopCommerce is a great example how NOT to do it. If they would have used the facade pattern at the start the contructors would not be as they are now.

An example of implementing this is in c# is here: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/06/18/the-facade-pattern-in-net.aspx

Where does the word facade comes from? I live in Holland. In Amsterdam you have beautiful Big houses if you take a roundtrip with a boat. The front of those houses you look at are called facades. They look beautiful from the outside, but in the old days there was not much beautiful to see inside.

What does that mean in IT-words? A facade hides whats behind it.

Comment: In the above example there are 4 dependencies. It seems hard if there are more to manage them, probably by creating sub systems.